# How to print all possible combinations of multiple characters?

Tags: algorithm, combinations, permutation

I am struggling to understand all the incomplete information I found about my question, so I hope you can help me. I want to write a program that prints all possible combinations of a string. For Example:

Given the string **ABC** *2, the program would print out:

- A; B; C
- AA; BB; CC; AB; AC; BC; BA; CA; CB
- AAA; BBB; CCC; AAB; AAC; ABB; ABC...
  and so on. *1

What algorithms should I use? I'm really a beginner in programming and I really struggle understanding the logic of a permutation algorithm, but I really got my mind into making this program.

Thanks.

*1 This prints out all three letter combinations of the letters a, b and c, in any order, as long as it's different from all of the previous entries.

*2 If the string is AAB, the output would be all combinations of A and B, but with three characters limit.

Comment: You should clarify the 'and so on' part.  Without a maximum size there is an unbounded number of combinations.

Comment: @huck_cussler, I guess for now I want to get the main logic of the program, so It's limited by the length of ABC, but in future I would like to add an implementation to, for example, print all combinations with a length limit.

Comment: What do you do if the input is 'AAB'?

Comment: @stark, do combinations of AB, with three characters limit.

Answer (score 0):

Split problem into two: first try to get all permutation when given its `size` and `alphabet` with distinct characters, e.g. C# code can be:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Permutations(int size, string alphabet) {
  StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder(new string(alphabet[0], size));

  while (true) {
    string result = word.ToString();

    yield return result;

    if (result.All(c => c == alphabet[alphabet.Length - 1]))
      break;

    for (int i = word.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
      if (result[i] == alphabet[alphabet.Length - 1])
        word[i] = alphabet[0];
      else {
        word[i] = alphabet[alphabet.IndexOf(word[i]) + 1];

        break;
      }
  }
}
```

Test:

```
// AA, AB, AC, BA, BB, BC, CA, CB, CC
Console.Write(string.Join(", ", Permutations(2, "ABC")));
```

Then *combine* permutations of different `size`s in case of C# implmentation it can be done easily with a help of *Linq*:

```
string alphabet = "ABA";
int limit = alphabet.Length; //TODO: it's unclear what limit is, put the right one
string distinctAlphabet = string.Concat(alphabet.OrderBy(c => c).Distinct());

var result = Enumerable.Range(1, limit)
  .Select(length => string.Join("; ", Permutations(length, distinctAlphabet)));

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Output (for `source = "ABC";`):

```
A; B; C
AA; AB; AC; BA; BB; BC; CA; CB; CC
AAA; AAB; AAC; ABA; ABB; ABC; ... ; CBB; CBC; CCA; CCB; CCC
```

Output (for `source = "ABA";`):

```
A; B
AA; AB; BA; BB
AAA; AAB; ABA; ABB; BAA; BAB; BBA; BBB
```